# I have a valid B1/B2 Visa for US, but is its validity affected by a change of residence?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, residency, visa-expiration

About 1.5 years ago, I got a B1/B2 visa that's valid for 10 years.

I've now moved to a different city within Germany.

The new city is entered in the passport.

Is there any impact on the validity of my USA visa associated with it? Do I have to somehow forward my new contact details to the embassy?

Comment: Change of city is not a material change invalidating the visa. Moving from a city in Germany to say a city in Iran (on the banned list) **could** be viewed as a material change, but definitely not a case like yours.

Answer (score 4):

I moved from Budapest, Hungary to Vancouver, BC, Canada and continued to use my ten year B1/B2 visa for a good eight years more with more border crossings than I am comfortable to admit (there was that week when I landed home on Monday and was already on a plane back to the USA on Thursday. Fun times). I didn't report this residency change, never got told to report it despite I was even in secondary once.